# How to maintain Timeout Session when calling Api Call in Loop Contion

Tags: javascript, session-timeout, clearinterval

i having Api Call which execute in For Loop some of the value which returns 10 sec itself some may take nearly 60 sec i have to maintain proper Timeout and clear session (i.e if results comes at 15 sec means it should goes to next input values and run the code) but currenly its waiting for 45 sec each single record how to optimize it

here my sample code :

```
if (selectedrows.length >= 1) {
for (var i = 0; i < selectedrows.length; i++) {
var myVar = setTimeout (function (k) {
    var ob = { results: "Appending ..." };

    child.update(selectedrows[k][4], selectedrows[k][4], ob);

    var fullName = selectedrows[k][1] + ' ' + selectedrows[k][2];
             math.ResultCall.async(fullName,function (err, res) {

   if (err) throw err;

        var returnedValue = JSON.parse(res);
        console.log(returnedValue);
        if(returnedValue.Result == null || returnedValue.Result.FOUND_Result == null)
       {
                console.log("None found")

            }
        else{

    var obj = { results: “res” };
    child.update(selectedrows[k][4], selectedrows[k][4], obj);

  }

}

});

 }, i * 45000,i);

}
}
```

Comment: why setTimeout is required? You can run without setTimeout?

Answer (score 0):

Rephrasing your question, you need to return the data when your api gets resolved.
For this please go through https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve

JavaScript, by default it work asynchronously because of its event loop.
You have promises and resolve to get notified when your api returns a data

Hope I helped :)

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches to implement the solution
1. [Async-Await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function): in-case the records-processing order is important

```
for( let i=0; i<selectedrows.length; i++)
{
  let ob = { results: "Appending ..." };

  child.update(selectedrows[i][4], selectedrows[i][4], ob);
  let fullName = selectedrows[i][1] + ' ' + selectedrows[i][2];

  await new Promise((resolve,reject)=> 
    {
      math.ResultCall.async(fullName,(err, res) => {
        if (err) reject(err);
        let returnedValue = JSON.parse(res);
        console.log(returnedValue);
       if(returnedValue.Result == null || returnedValue.Result.FOUND_Result == null) {
            console.log("None found")
        } else {
           let obj = { results: “res” };
           child.update(selectedrows[i][4], selectedrows[i][4], obj);
         }
     resolve();
    });
}
```

**don't forget this means the wrapping function should be async as well (which returns a promise that can be resolved if necessary)

2.[Promise.All](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all): if the order is not important

```
let promArray = [];
for( let i=0; i<selectedrows.length; i++)
{
  let ob = { results: "Appending ..." };

  child.update(selectedrows[i][4], selectedrows[i][4], ob);
  let fullName = selectedrows[i][1] + ' ' + selectedrows[i][2];
  promArray.push( new Promise((resolve,reject)=> 
    {
      math.ResultCall.async(fullName,(err, res) => {
        if (err) reject(err);
        let returnedValue = JSON.parse(res);
        console.log(returnedValue);
       if(returnedValue.Result == null || returnedValue.Result.FOUND_Result == null) {
            console.log("None found")
        } else {
           let obj = { results: “res” };
           child.update(selectedrows[i][4], selectedrows[i][4], obj);
         }
     resolve();
    });
  ); 
}
Promise.all(promArray);
```

** this will also return a Promise that can be resolved if necessary.

Comment: tried first example got error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token new